# To check if a variable is integer

Tags: c++

so basically I'm dividing two numbers entered by the user and storing it in a variable. that variable is time, so it can neither be negative nor any fractional part. It has to be a +ve integer and I've to check for it.

```
int main()
{
    int x1,v1,x2,v2;
    cin>>x1>>v1>>x2>>v2;
    int p=x1-x2;
    int q=v2-v1;
    float t=p/q;
    int x=floor(t);
    int y=ceil(t);
    int temp;
    if(x==y)
     temp=1; 
    if(t>0 && temp==1)
    cout<<"YES";
    else
    cout<<"NO";
}
```

But even for a number like 2341/124, it is returning 'YES'.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/div

Comment: Try `float t = (float)p/q`

Comment: Are you competing with someone for the program with the shortest average-length variable names?

Comment: To expand on @Odysseus's comment: Your `float t=p/q` will be doing integer division, since both operands are `int`. The `int` result is then stored in `t`.

Comment: Since `temp` is not initialized, comparing its value to `1` doesn't tell you anything meaningful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`p/q` does not produce a `float`.

Both `p` and `q` are integers, so integer division is performed, and the result is a "rounded down" version of the mathematical answer, as another `int`.

It doesn't matter that you then assign this new integer to a `float`.

Avoid this by casting one side to `float` *before* the division, or by using [`std::div`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/div).

By the way, speaking generally, a time duration can be both negative and non-integral.